# C# - Json Deserialize doesn't work correctly?

Tags: c#, json

I have an C# program which calls a website API to get a JSON response:

```
{"success":true, "taskid":"1466687729433", "tasktype":"kkk", "steamid":32323, "value":5.68, "token":"sadsad", "items":[5751210424, 5751210304], "botid":1}
```

Then I'm using it like this:

```
    public Task checkForTasks()
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task>(base.Bot.SteamWeb.Fetch("LinkHere", "GET", null, false, ""));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return new Task { success = false };
    }
```

But I keep getting error in my output console:

> Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll

What could cause that?

Comment: What is the return of `base.Bot.SteamWeb.Fetch("WebsiteLink", "GET", null, false, "")`?

Comment: It's returning the JSON data, if there is.

Comment: Basically same as httpwebrequest.

Comment: As a string? Have you done a print to make sure the information is correct?

Comment: Thers most likely something wrong with your input string.try to get it before passing it in the deserializer.

Comment: I can see it myself on the URL. I'm sure it won't change for there.

Comment: @AleksKpur Any chance you're referencing **System.Threading.Tasks.Task** in '**JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task>**'

Comment: I edited my first post, for the task

Comment: Show the stack trace and your `Task` class and also can you include the using declaration's

Comment: What is the exception _message_ anyway?

Comment: Show us the definition of the `Task` class.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a valid json:

{"success":true, "taskid":"", "tasktype":"", "steamid":, "value":, "token":"", "items":[5751210424, 5751210304], **"botid":**}

try with something like:

{"success":true, "taskid":"", "tasktype":"", "steamid":, "value":"", "token":"", "items":[5751210424, 5751210304], "botid": 1}

Well I copy your json to my visual studio with special paste it gives me error while generating relevant class

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "taskid": "",
    "tasktype": "",
    "steamid": ,
    "value": ,
    "token": "",
    "items": [5751210424, 5751210304],
    "botid":
}
```

`value` and `botid` are missing. The deserializer cannot deserialize incomplete JSON.

Comment: Naah, I just removed those myself.

Comment: Then fix you question and don't show us invalid JSON. What is the exception message? What is the definition of the `Task` class? Why do I even have to ask such questions?

Comment: Still the exception _message_ is missing. Still the _usings_ are missing. Still the _definition of the `Task` class_ is missing...

Comment: I don't know the exception message. I can just see that text in output window.

Comment: Do you have access to the source of the program? Can you debug it?

Comment: Yes, I have the source open with me

Comment: Then make sure VS breaks on exceptions in the `DEBUG` >  `Exceptions...`dialog, debug the application and check the exception message.

Comment: Okay so, It seems like for that return it's null value. What could cause that?